# R: Get p-value for all coefficients in multiple linear regression (incl. reference level)

Tags: r, regression, p-value

**Example**

I have a linear regression, which fits a numerical dependent variable with 3 explanatory factor variables. Each of the factor variables has 2 levels.

```
install.packages("robustbase")
install.packages("MASS")
require(robustbase)
require(MASS)

# Example data
data(npk)
df= npk[,-1]
str(df) 

# 'data.frame':  24 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ N    : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 ...
# $ P    : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 ...
# $ K    : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 ...
# $ yield: num  49.5 62.8 46.8 57 59.8 58.5 55.5 56 62.8 55.8 ...

set.seed(0)
model <- lmrob(yield ~ N + P + K - 1, data= df)
```

**Task**

I want to access the p-values for each coefficient of the `model` object. To avoid an unnecessary intercept I am already using `- 1` in the formula.

```
summary(model)$coefficients

# Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
# N0 54.644672   2.400075 22.7678995 8.972084e-16
# N1 60.166737   1.966661 30.5933467 2.858276e-18
# P1 -1.059299   2.139443 -0.4951286 6.259053e-01
# K1 -3.905052   2.226012 -1.7542822 9.469295e-02
```

Seems that the baseline (reference) levels for `P` and `K` are hidden.

**Question**

How can I change the code to access the p-values also for `P0`and `K0` as coefficients for the `model` object?

**Note:** I am not sure if it makes a difference for the solution, that I am actually using in my real problem `lmrob` as robust regression function, so I decided to better keep it in this reproducible example.

Comment: The p-values are for contrasts between a factor value and a reference value. When using treatment contrasts as is the default for R, the reference level of a factor coefficient is the first level. The `Intercept` is the estimated level for a hypothetical case where all the factor values are at their base levels. Hence, you can hardly call that estimate "unnecessary".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The p-values that are estimated are:

```
coef(summary(model))[, 4]
```

Regarding the reference levels, the model is using treatment contrasts so the values of the reference levels are all zero thus its not meaningful to ask for their p-values.

Comment: OK. Works. But it does not show better variables based on p-value (such as *, **, **). Any other way to do that?